# Best practice to refactor if staments in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

what's the best practice to refactor the following c# code: Can replace this with Strategy pattern?

```
    private int GetAccountType(int balance)
    {
        if (balance <= 5000)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (balance > 5000 && balance <= 10000)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (balance >= 10001)
        {
            return 3;
        }

        _logger.LogError("Invalid AccountType");
        // TO DO : Throw custom exception
        throw new Exception("Invalid Balance");
    }
```

Comment: To me this is the most clear way to express your logic. Why do you want to refactor this code?

Comment: strategy-pattern in this instance would definitly be over-engineering. also: your code can never (ever) reach your logger.

Comment: The only thing i would say is I never use else if the first expression has a ret7rn since it is redundant

Comment: You could, but you should consider if you _should_

Comment: Agree Strategy would be over-engineering, in this case.. Dunno if this can be called a "refactoring" but if you hardcode things like the above, you may as well issue return (balance>10000)?3:((4999+balance)/5000) without any if statements.

Comment: you can use Enums  to better express your accounttype . That beeing said, the example is far to minimal to justify a strategy pattern.

Comment: *switch expression* is the "modern" way of writing such things. just search the term and you'll find a lot of examples.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann . . . "strategy-pattern in this instance would definitely be over-engineering". You *might* be right, but IMHO that's just a subjective and opinionated remark. A lot of scenarios here on SO are just simplified samples to reproduce an issue. Purely regarding the OP's question, applying a strategy pattern *could* be a valid refactoring choice. Where would you put the boundary for deciding when to use a simple if/switch construct and where to use an "over-engineered" strategy pattern exactly?

Comment: @BartHofland simple. if i can understand the code within 5 or less seconds, _before_ i had my morning coffee, then every solution slightly more complex is over-engineered. (and if the _complexity_ grounds for asking whether or not to use strategy, then - obviously - an example with reduced complexity and no hint that it is reduced will result in inadequate answers.)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann . . . Great. I agree. Well, at that regard, I would at least propose to introduce an enum for the account type, which replaces the magic numbers `1`, `2`, and `3`. And perhaps declare two constants for the magic numbers `5000` and `10000` as well. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can refactor in another way :

```
int result = balance > 5000 && balance <= 10000 ? 2 : balance > 10000 ? 3 : 1;
```

### Few lines

1. There are no fundamental difference between ternary and if/else.
2. Ternary is faster then if/else as long as no additional computation is required to convert the logic to us ternary. When it is a simply ternary operation, it has better readability as well.
3. If only statement is faster than if/else, so if the logic doesn’t require an else statement, do use it.

Performance Comparison : [LINK](https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/what-is-the-fastest-conditional-statement)

## Strategy Design Pattern

It is behavioral design pattern and you can implement when you have such issues. This code doesn't require patterns as it will be over engineering.

**Identification**: Strategy pattern can be recognized by a method that lets nested object do the actual work, as well as the setter that allows replacing that object with a different one

**Usage examples**: It’s often used in various frameworks to provide users a way to change the behavior of a class without extending it.

Comment: don't forget negative numbers  :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree with using ternary operator for this. The biggest difference is readability. It is really hard to read. I think your colleague's will favor a if/else vs a long ternary on one line.

Comment: I got you and agree up to some extent. Readability vs performance is the answer of your concern. Also you can introduce parenthesis to make more readable. i.e. LINQ, LAMDA are the examples for few people hard to read as well.  Hope this help @RvdK Cheers!

Comment: @RvdK Really? And how is if statement more readable when you need to follow else if blocks, and realize when exactly they are hit etc. Compared to the optimal for this case `=> balance > 10000 ? 3 : balance > 5000 : 2 : 1`. You can easily see the limits and the corresponding map. Anyway, reading the comments, all they prove is that this is opinionated question.

Comment: I don't like the unreadability of this approach and I would certainly split it over several lines, but more importantly, I would reorder the conditions here: `int result = balance > 10000 ? 3 : balance > 5000 ? 2 : 1;`. This would simplify the conditional logic somewhat. (Like in Hans Kestings answer and in Ivan Stoev's comment).

Comment: I wouldn't bother with performance considerations before having looked at the bigger picture.

Comment: @IvanStoev and pashyant: I was not clear on my comment. This is indeed very opinionated. What I was trying to say was that refactoring should always prioritize readability. Check with your team what they prefer. Ternary are fine, but having more than one line I always try to do some cross checking if it really makes it 'better'.

Comment: Agreed, i guess we are inline. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't add link to java performance benchmark from 2013 because .net is entirely different and there was 8 years optimizations

Comment: A link to a almost 10-years old article about Java as an answer to C# question isn't the best answer. Also, "better readability" is an opinion: I find the `if` much more readable.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already mentioned Strategy would definitely be over-engineering in this case. Since your logging statement is never reached, I'd simply do:

```
 private int GetAccountType(int balance)
    {
        return balance switch
        {
            <= 5000 => 1,
            > 5000 and <= 10000 => 2,
            >= 10001 => 3
        };
    }
```

But normally I would not refactor anything in this case - perhaps just remove the "else".

Comment: Good to point out the unreachable code and the possible usage of the `switch`-expression here. :) I still would argue that determining that a strategy pattern would be overkill is correct. If this if/switch-logic (or its result) would be used in multple locations, using a strategy pattern might quickly become a valid refactoring choice. I personally feel that it is difficult to determine this just on a simple code sample.

Comment: Switch expression is new in C# 8.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Answer (score 4):

One easy simplification would be:

```
private int GetAccountType(int balance)
{
    if (balance <= 5000)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (balance <= 10000) // balance is certain to be > 5000
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else // balance is certain to be > 10000
    {
        return 3;
    }

    _logger.LogError("Invalid AccountType");
    // TO DO : Throw custom exception
    throw new Exception("Invalid Balance");
}
```

If you already checked that `balance <= 5000` then in the else-if you don't need to check that `balance > 5000` - you wouldn't get there otherwise.

For the rest your logic is clear this way - readability is also an important aspect!

Answer (score 2):

In case you have many balances, I suggest *extracting a model*:

```
// Note, now you can add easily as many balances as you want
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Func<int>> s_Balances = 
  new Dictionary<int, int>() {
    { int.MinValue, 1}, // 1 starting from int.MinValue + 1
    {         5000, 2}, // 2 starting from 5001
    {        10000, 3}, // 3 starting from 10001
};
```

then you can easily query this model with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private int GetAccountType(int balance) {
  int key = s_Balances
    .Keys
    .Where(k < balance)
    .Max();

  return s_Balances[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, but I think the if/else statement is more readable. I added it because it can be a useful technique when you need to look up values in an array for instance.

```
using static System.Math;
...
private int GetAccountType(int balance) => 1 + Min(Max(balance / 5000, 0), 2);
```

Comment: A bit easier implementation of your idea is `=> 1 + Clamp(balance / 5000, 0, 2);`